# SQL Monitoring Overview

Tags: sql, monitoring

I currently loook after 20 odd databases in SQL server 2005 and need a tool for monitoring the performance and keep me informed if a database is running slow. Is there anything I can run within Managment studio of any other good third party tool (Pref free) that can do the job.

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably get more and better answers on Serverfault.com - that's where the DBA's and monitoring guys hang out, more so than here...

Comment: check out SCOM from MS, and products from RedGate and Idera

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Quest tool suite for SQL Server Management and Monitoring:

http://www.quest.com/sql-server/

Check out [Spotlight on SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-sql-server-enterprise/) - I would think that's roughly what you might be looking for (but I'm not a full-time DBA or systems admin....)

Answer (score 1):

On the free:

[SQLMonitoring Tool](http://sqlmonitoring.codeplex.com/)

[SQL Server 2005 Performance Dashboard Reports](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en)

[Confio Ignite Free](http://www.ignitefree.com/) - Check this one out. It is amazing! The free version will monitor up to twenty instances. Based on the size of your environment, I think this will do everything you need and more.

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate's tool can be found at:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Response/index.htm

To be clear, I work here at Red Gate, so I would plug our tool, but - we have a fully functional 14 day trial. Try it out and see what you think..

Answer (score 0):

Two freebies you already have, Perfmon and Profiler will do everything you need, I've used them alone to tune and monitor fairly large setups. Run Profiler to watch for long running queries, and run Perfmon to watch CPU and disk I/O ranges.